# How to do a drag and drop feature in an aspx web page?

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, imagebutton, drag

I tried putting the image button inside a div and making the div draggable but I can only drag the image button from its borders. How can I enable drag and drop on an aspx web page?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us your code and what you have tried? Thanks.

Comment: well you can put the image inside a panel and with ajax drag panel extender you can drag and drop the image,